# Magento 1.9.1 Helper Class not found error

Tags: magento-1.9, php

While creating the new page in Admin panel, getting the error as `Fatal error: Class 'Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/bitkarshop/app/Mage.php on line 547` My config files are as follows..

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <menu>
       <main_menu translate="title" module="example">
           <title>Main Menu</title>
               <sort_order>1</sort_order>
               <children>
               <sub_menu1 translate="title" >
                    <title>Sub Menu 1</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/submenu1</action>
               </sub_menu1>
               </children>
       </main_menu>
   </menu>
</config>
```

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </add_category_attribute>
        </resources>

        <helpers>
      <example>
         <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper</class>
      </example>
   </helpers>
    </global>
....
```

> In app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Helper\Data.php

```
<?

class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data{          

}
```

Once going to Admin panel i am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/bitkarshop/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `<?php` tag.

Change this

```
<?

class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data{          

}
```

to

```
<?php
class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{          

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are either missing the helper definition in `config.xml`:

```
<config>
  ...
  <global>
    ...
    <helpers>
      <ddevs_ebayaff>
        <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper</class>
      </ddevs_ebayaff>
    </helpers>
    ...
```

or should add `module="example"` to `adminhtml.xml`, the `<sub_menu1 translate="title" >` node

```
<sub_menu1 translate="title" module="example" >
```

### Edit

As a best practice, if you're using a translate attribute, you should also define a module default helper.

Answer (score 1):

in file

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Helper\Data.php
>   It should be modified as below

```
<?php

class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data{          

}
```