# My magento module is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, helper

Please help me guys to fix it :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Parcelamento_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp64\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547
```

**Error log**

> Warning: include(Mage\Parcelamento\Helper\Data.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line
>   94

I'm not a programmer, it's so hard. Can you help me , please ?

[Module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66I9AyUOaAnS21VMmNFSlEwSEk)

Comment: Wrong attachment

Comment: please check this might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70934/magento-1-9-1-helper-class-not-found-error

Comment: You need to upload Autoload.php in the Varien folder. Path:  lib/Varien/

Answer (score 0):

go to your magento directory

`app/code/local OR Community/Bizcommerce/Parcelamento/Helper`

and create file named `Data.php`

and write below code init

```
<?php
    class Bizcommerce_Parcelamento_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{} 
?>
```